# Win7 File maybe locked

Tags: windows-7

When i start and quit an program (no matter which one), then i cannot overwrite
this exe-file for some minutes. This is very annoying during programming:

As example: After compile and start/quit the program (to test it) i cannot compile
for some minutes, because the file seems to be locked. But "Unlocker" as example shows no lock.

Any idea what to do ?  The behaviour is new !

Comment: Does it happen with any EXE or just a specific one? Is it visible in the Task Manager after you close it?

Comment: This happens with any exe. and after closing it, it is no longer in taskmanager listed.